# Pageless not working well with Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have tried to use pageless to implement without any success and the demo seems to be rather limited in giving me insight on using pageless in new java. When I run this and scroll down, loading message and gif appears but doesn't update...

In ApplicableIc.retrieve returns results found from this query

```
  paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40, :conditions => [retrieve_cond,*values], 
    :order => "#{params[:order]}, qrisk, platform, submodule, feature, root_name, suite_name, case_name, ic_name")
```

In Controller

```
def current_objects
  if !params[:project_id].blank? && !params[:start_date].blank? && !params[:end_date].blank?
    @current_objects ||= ApplicableIc.retrieve(params.merge(:order => "root_name,suite_name,case_name,ic_name"))
    if !@current_objects.any?
      flash.now[:error] = "No Results for these parameters, please change your inputs"
    end
    @current_objects
  end
end
```

In html.haml View

```
.container#applicable_ics 
  -if @applicable_ics
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
        %th= sortable "Executed Platforms"
        %th= sortable "Passed Platforms"
         ...
      %tbody=render :partial => "applicable_ics"
    = will_paginate(@applicable_ics)
    = pageless(250, "Loading next '#{@applicable_ics.per_page}' of  '#{@applicable_ics.total_entries}' rows", @applicable_ics.total_pages, "#{url_for params.except(:page).merge(:format => :js)}")
```

Application helper

```
def pageless(distance, loaderMsg, total_pages, url=nil, container=nil)
  yell "comes here pageless"
  opts = {
  :distance => distance, 
  :totalPages => total_pages,
  :url        => url,
  :loaderMsg  => loaderMsg,
  :loaderImage => image_path("indicator.gif")
  }

  container && opts[:container] ||= container

  javascript_tag("$('#applicable_ics tbody').pageless(#{opts.to_json});")
end
```

Any insight, guidance or help would be appreciated

Comment: Ok for people who want to use make resourceful and pageless that it is impossible or very difficult to use both together.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, you are passing in "conditions" and "order" keys to the paginate constructor. They should be queried using active record.

Change

```
 paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40, :conditions => [retrieve_cond,*values], 
:order => "#{params[:order]}, qrisk, platform, submodule, feature, root_name, suite_name, case_name, ic_name")
```

To this

```
YourModel.find(:all, :conditions => [retrieve_cond,*values]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40).order("#{params[:order]}, qrisk, platform, submodule, feature, root_name, suite_name, case_name, ic_name")
```